# Unexpected multiplication results with integer values read by scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I am a beginner at C and I am trying to write a vector multiplication code. I read in an array and the scale. Then I multiply this scale with each element in the array.

```
for (i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++) 
{
    scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
}

puts("Please enter the scale:");
scanf("%d", s);

puts("The scaled vector is:");

for (j = 0 ; j < 5 ; j++) 
{
    int r = numbers[j] * s  ;
    printf("%d\n", r);
}
```

However, when I run this code I receive unexpected values with the following inputs:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Scale:

```
2
```

Output:

```
6130616
12261232
18391848
24522464
30653080
```

When I replace the `s` in here `numbers[j] * s` by 2, for example, it will return the expected output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Send a pointer to scanf, so that you can get the value:

```
puts ("Please enter the scale:");
scanf ("%d" , &s);
```

Comment: Probably it's a typo since he did it right a few lines above. Nice spot by the way, I didn't notice it ;)

Comment: +1, and I'll bet his compiler agreed (*uninitialized local variable 's' used* or the like).